# Accessing all elements in a JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following structure in my JSON:

```
{
    "function": "ComAl_Set_nad_crtl_xcall_state",
    "timeStamp": 1488516897797,
    "Param1": "SIG_NAD_CRTL_XCALL_STATE",
    "Value1": "8"
},
{
    "function": "ComAl_Set_nad_crtl_xcall_state",
    "timeStamp": 1488516912217,
    "Param1": "SIG_NAD_CRTL_XCALL_STATE",
    "Value1": "10"
},
```

I create this json by getting using the following method:

```
def get_json_from_stub(self, file_name):
    def jsonize_stub(raw_data):
        end = raw_data.rfind(",")
        parsed_data = "[" + raw_data[:end] + "]" 
        return json.loads(parsed_data.replace("\00", ""))

    command = "'cat "  + self.stub_path + file_name + "'"
    content =  self.send_ssh_command(command)
    json_stub = jsonize_stub(content)
    return json_stub
```

So far I only needed the last value1 from the JSON, which I am getting like this:

```
def get_last_element(self, json_stub, value='Value1'):
    last_element_from_json = json_stub[-1].get(value)
    if len(json_stub) > 0 and last_element_from_json is not None:
        return last_element_from_json
    else:
        pass
```

my question is can I get the previous value1 as well (for example in my JSON value1: 8 and value1: 10) because for now, I get this value using json_stub[-1] which will always give me the last value? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-2` to get the second from last.

```
json_stub[-2]
```

In Python negative index points to an element from right-to-left of the list as opposed to the default left-to-right. `-1` for the the last element (left-to-right), `-2` for the second from last (left-to-right) etc.